# Ключей в словаре меньше чем должно быть

Tags: словари, python-3.6

У меня тут одна проблема и своих знаний пока не хватает для решения этой задачи.Если поможете буду очень благодарен.
Есть excel с данными имя, возраст и т.д. Написал функцию которая берет все эти данные и впихивает в словарь.Excel файл состоит из 102382 строк.Но в моем словаре только 101777 ключей.Не могу понять куда делись 600 человек. :/

[Полный код на пастебин](https://pastebin.com/wAM4sNjz)

```
for i in range(begin_r, mrow_sec + 1):
    name_sec = wsheet_sec.cell(row = i, column = 2).value
    new_n_sec = name_sec

    # Заполняем наш словарь списком-значениями у которых ключ это фамилия-имя-отчество        
    sv_b_date_sec = wsheet_sec.cell(row = i, column = 3).value
    sv_num_sec = wsheet_sec.cell(row = i, column = 7).value
    # Что то тупит.Иногда нужно изменить datetime тип в строку
    sv_date_sec = wsheet_sec.cell(row = i, column = 8).value.strftime('%d.%m.%Y') # Делает из типа datetime строку типа str
    sv_reg_sec = wsheet_sec.cell(row = i, column = 9).value
    sec_dict.update({new_n_sec:[i, sv_b_date_sec, sv_num_sec, sv_date_sec, sv_reg_sec]})           

return sec_dict
```

Вот этот цикл отвечает за заполнения словаря.На втором столбце excel файла только данные "Фамилия Имя Отчество" и я использую их как ключи.Не понимаю просто.Он просто должен скопировать эти данные.Куда могуть пропасть 600 человек? :(

Comment: Это будет жёстко, но для начала следует выявить этих 600 участников и определить, что у них общего. А там до ответа недалеко.

Comment: Там 102382 человека!!! :D Но.... я могу написать программу которая проверит кто не попал в тот словарь.Гениально!!!Спасибо за совет! :3

Comment: Написал тест проверку.Все люди из excel файла внутри словаря(тест так показал). :/ Исключения должны были напечататься на экран.Но их не было.Может код проверки количества ключей у меня не правильная....Погуглю еще.

Comment: Метод len() указал что длинна словаря 101778.Просто какая то магия :D

Comment: Я Питон знаю очень поверхностно, но если len() работает по типу strlen() из С, то вполне возможно какие-то значения считаются "концом строки" и дальше расчёт не идёт. Но если по типу Паскаля, то это уже баг.

Comment: Ну я проверял через len() и еще старым дедовским методом через for.Короче не могу понять.Это выше моих сил. -_-